# Load content ajax in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have one page site structure. This is my menu:

I have a menu structure:

```
 <ul id="creamenu" class="menuHolder">
                        <li><a id="news-1-menu" href="#/creative-events">news 1</a></li>
                        <li><a id="news-2-menu" href="#/creative-ajans">news 2</a></li>
                        <li><a id="news-3-menu" href="#/incentive-travel">news 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="mainmenu" class="menuHolder">
                        <li><a id="about1-menu" href="#/hakkimizda">about 1</a></li>
                        <li><a id="about2-menu" href="#/haberler">about 2</a></li>
                        <li><a id="about3-menu" href="#/galeri">about 3</a></li>
                        <li><a id="about4-menu" href="#/referanslar">about 4</a></li>
                        <li><a id="about5-menu" href="#/iletisim">about 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And this is content structure:

```
<div id='news-1'>
    <!-- content -->
    <!-- content -->
```

```
<div id='news-2'>
    <!-- content -->
    <!-- content -->
```

When i click a menu item, go to page via Parallax effect (I'm using premium plugin for this) But my site is slowly... Because, i want when i click a menu item, load content via ajax. Is it possible? How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the content is in other file, then you can do with `$.load(url).`

```
$('#news-1').load('url of the content to load');
```

if you storing the content in same page, then you can make it visible when menu clicked.

```
$('#news-1').on('click',function(){
$('#news-1').appendTo($('#creative-events').html()); // this is the prototype, need to make a generic code
})
```

Comment: no all contents in same page.

Comment: ''if you storing the content in same page, then you can make it visible when menu clicked.'' but how?

Comment: I don't know why but this code don't working Ravi. Other solution idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
$('ul#creamenu li a').click(function () {
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Your Url",
                data: "{'data':'send data here if you want'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.Stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

});
```

Comment: All contents in same page. So, don't work this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#news-1').load('ajax/page1.html');
 $('#news-2').load('ajax/page2.html');
```

Comment: All contents in same page. So, don't work this.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are looking for a solution like tabbed panels. Try hiding and showing divs by using jQuery..
For ex. u have 3 menus as news-1,news-2,news-3 and make their seperate content divs ex:div1,div2,div3 like follows...

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
some content....
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
some content....
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none">
some content....
</div>
```

at onclick event of the menu for ex. news-1 then show div1 and let all others hidden as follows..

```
$("#div2").hide();
$("#div3").hide();
$("#div1").show();
```

then change the code for other menus as well..

Comment: you said all the contents which are related to all menus are in same page. Is that right?